# Where exactly YII_DEBUG is defined?

Tags: yii

I have a standard (auto-generated) `index.php` bootstrap file for my Yii application. It contains:

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', TRUE);
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL', 3);
```

When I put these two lines:

```
var_dump(defined('YII_DEBUG'));
var_dump(YII_DEBUG);
```

below definition of these two Yii constants, I'm getting an excepted behavior (two times `true`).

When I comment first line of first code block (`YII_DEBUG` definition) I'm also getting an expected results -- `false` + `Notice: Use of undefined constant YII_DEBUG`.

Strange things starts to happen, when I leave definition of `YII_DEBUG` commented, but move these two `var_dump` lines from `index.php` and put them in the beginning of my configuration file.

I expected the very same behavior (nothing has changed, `YII_DEBUG` remains undefined), but instead I'm getting `true` + `false`.

What has happened? What I'm missing? **At which point of Yii application life-cycle the `YII_DEBUG` constant has become defined**?

**EDIT**: *Adding `print_r(get_defined_constants(true)['user']);` below these two `var_dump` confirms, that `YII_DEBUG` is defined in second scenario and undefined in first one*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`YII_DEBUG` is set to `false` in [YiiBase.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/c3dc6a11964acb8042ee0f58bd21785640d87572/framework/YiiBase.php), that gets called by [yii.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/633e54866d54bf780691baaaa4a1f847e8a07e23/framework/yii.php), that is included in your `index.php`